# Failure of yarn upgrade

Tags: yarnpkg

When I want to upgrade a dependency of my project (`lodash` package), I run the following command:

```
yarn upgrade lodash
```

I face with the following error:

```
yarn upgrade v1.12.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/path-postId/-/path-postId-2.0.1.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "Unexpected end of data"
```

I consulted the mentioned [page](http://info%20Visit%20https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade%20for%20documentation%20about%20this%20command.) but I couldn't find any useful information to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps resolved the problem:

1. Remove the `yarn.lock` file.

   ```
   rm yarn.lock
   ```
2. Recreate the `yarn.lock` file by running the following command:

   ```
   yarn install
   ```
3. Upgrade the dependency using `--skip-integrity-check`:

   ```
   yarn upgrade --skip-integrity-check lodash
   ```